# Facebook login PHP permissions

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I am trying to create a Facebook login using PHP I have found something online that I am using to do it so far. Unfortunately it only asks for the basic profile information, I am wanting to have it request the friends as well. I have tried to do this from the code but It isn't asking for the permission. How can I request the permission?

[Link To Website](http://friends.esy.es/1353/fbconfig.php)

```
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me');
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response


  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $fbfriends = $graphObject->getProperty('friends'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['FRIENDS'] = $fbfriends;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this. It is not the only way I think but it works for me.

**index.php**

```
    <?php

      require_once __DIR__ . '\..\src\Facebook\autoload.php';

    session_start();

     $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '???',
      'app_secret' => '???',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
      ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = ['email','user_friends', 'publish_actions', 'user_posts']; //here you set all the permisions 
// (be aware that for some permisions you'll need to send your app to Facebook Review)
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

    echo htmlspecialchars($loginUrl); // this will echo the URL that needs to be clicked (something like 'Login with Facebook' button)

    ?>
```

**fb-callback.php**

```
<?php
  require_once __DIR__ . '\..\src\Facebook\autoload.php';
  session_start();
 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '???', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '???',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}
// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);
// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('???'); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();
if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }
  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}
$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');
header('Location: http://localhost/page_after_login');
?>
```

**EDIT**: This code corresponds to Facebook Login Example from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Comment: is this a new file? If so where is it going to be saved?

Comment: Yes is a new file. You can save it anywhere you want and then modify the URL of $loginUrl. Please read this (for me was very helpful): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Comment: I have done all that you have said but I seem to get an error of some sort. What did I do wrong? 
Warning: require_once(/home/u742400531/public_html/1353http://friends.esy.es/1353/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u742400531/public_html/1353/index.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/u742400531/public_html/1353http://friends.esy.es/1353/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u742400531/public_html/1353/index.php on line 3

Comment: It seems that your website is hosted on an free hosting service. I'm sorry to say but there are lots of problems with free hosting services when comes to FB API because they blocked connections to API. You'll need to develop your website on localhost or another hosting service.

Comment: Sorry I didn't look closely. Your problem is here (/home/u742400531/public_html/1353http://friends.esy.es/1353/autoloa‌​d.php) you need to change your 'require' to point to the autoload.php witch you can find it in Facebook API directory (if you install it manually). Look here for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted . Even if you solve this problem, keep in mind that you can't use Facebook API on free hosting services.