# Can't retrieve email from facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on facebook login using graph api v2.2
unfortunately I am not able to retrieve the email address from the code below

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'xxx', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
    if ($helper->getError()) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
        echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
        echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
        echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Bad request';
    }
    exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($tokenMetadata);
echo '</pre>';

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('{app-id}'); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    try {
        $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
        exit;
    }

    echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
    var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

$response = $fb->get('/me/?fields=email',$_SESSION['fb_access_token']);

print_r($response);
```

This is the response I am getting -

```
Access Token
string(163) "xxx"
Metadata
Facebook\Authentication\AccessTokenMetadata Object
(
    [metadata:protected] => Array
        (
            [app_id] => XXX
            [type] => USER
            [application] => XXX
            [expires_at] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2018-08-01 11:57:44.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [is_valid] => 1
            [issued_at] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2018-06-02 11:57:44.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [scopes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => email
                    [1] => public_profile
                )

            [user_id] => XXX
        )

)
```

But I am not able to get the email address  I was trying to look for code examples over here but couldn't find something the can fit

I was trying to use this $response = $fb->get('/me/?fields=email',$_SESSION['fb_access_token']); in order to get the data

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask for this specific permission to the user. 
Specify it in your code with this parameter :

```
$permissions = ['email']; //here you set all the permisions
```

that you have to send with this line (or equivalent, in your code) :

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);
```

This Stack Overflow page seems to answer your questions with more details :
[Facebook login PHP permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777179/facebook-login-php-permissions) or see the [official Facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login?locale=fr_FR).